# Using groupby to count a percent for each user

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    completed       User
0      false       sftcb
1       true      jsftcb
2       true      aynood
3       true     poantar
4      false      aynood
5       true       brrow
6       true       brrow
7       true       paose
8       true       pimes
9      false       brrow
```

What I want to get the percentages of "true" for each user. I tried using:

```
df1 = df.groupby('user')
```

But this did not perform the operation. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Because the name is capital u. `User`,

Comment: Expected output is exactly like what @Celius Stingher posted. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Josmoor98's answer, you should do a `mapping` first, because of the values being interpreted as strings. If you wish to display the values as % with a fixed amount of decimal places, then you use pandas `option.display.float_format`:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format
df['completed'] = df['completed'].map({'true':True,'false':False})
print(df.groupby('User')['completed'].mean()*100)
```

Output:

```
User
aynood    50.00%
brrow     67.67%
jsftcb    100.00%
paose     100.00%
pimes     100.00%
poantar   100.00%
sftcb     0.00%
Name: complete, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes sure. May be its a rookie question but how can i change 0.5000 to 50%

Comment: You can use pandas option display, edited in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you received a `KeyError` here. You can try the following.

```
df.groupby('User').mean() * 100
```